# Is Webpack 5 production ready?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I know that upgrading from v4 can cause issues with existing plugins and loaders but can I start using Webpack 5 in a new project in production reliably?

Specifically for Module Federation to use with React.

Comment: I'm watching the releases for webpack repository and I still see significant bugfixes. I would say that it is not ready yet as of today.